# Execute Oracle 'for update skip locked' clause with Tomcat DataSource not working

Tags: sql, tomcat7, jndi, spring-jdbc

I am working on a spring application which select rows from an Oracle8i DB in locked mode. Am using Tomcat7.0.57. I have configure my data source in context.xml as below.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:SID"
              username="user1" password="pwd1" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"/>
```

In my spring application context i have mentioned lookup statement as

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="testds" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
```

Using Spring jdbcTemplate am execute below select query

```
select * from employees where deptno=3 for update skip locked
```

I am getting this error

```
StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from employees where deptno=3 for update skip locked]; SQL state [null]; error code [17410]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No more data to read from socket
```

However as a temporary fix am using apache BasicDataSource to test my functionality.

```
<bean id="clarifyds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

But when deploying in UAT and Prod environments i need to lookup data source configured in context.xml

This problem is when using select query with 'for update' clause. It is working fine with simple select query.

Any ideas please suggest

Comment: Are you using the same jdbc driver for your `BasicDataSource` (i.e. in WEB-INF/lib) and your data source (driver in tomcat/lib)?

Comment: Yes am using same jdbc driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: And there aren't two different jars?

Comment: Am using same set of jars